# Does a COM Shell Interface exist for common prompts?

Tags: shell, winapi, com

I've been finding all kinds of Shell Interfaces via COM that help prevent reinventing the wheel when you have a Windows only application.  One thing I haven't found is something that will put up standard messages like the question to overwrite an existing file (where it also shows the source and target file with icons, dates and such).   Does something exists for that (outside of MFC/.NET)?

TIA!!

Comment: Sounds [like IFileOperation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifileoperation).  No, the "prompts" are not a separate component.  TaskDialog can provide reasonably standard-looking dialogs but is not a COM component and customization options are limited:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/task-dialogs

Comment: It would not, however, surprise me if the prompts are available through some message catalog. (Though I'm also not sure where it would be found).

Comment: @SoronelHaetir I doubt it, those dialogs have changed multiple times over the years. Certainly XP to Vista and maybe 7 to 8, I don't remember exactly.